# Getting this error "unused import statement in pycharm" while writing the script for Robotic Framework

Tags: pycharm, robotframework

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation    Demo Login

Resource  Resources/Common.robot



*** Test Cases ***
Common.Open URL
```

While referencing the Resources under Resource I am getting error as Unused import statement in pycharm

Comment: have you contacted pycharm customer support? Stackoverflow doesn't do product support.

Answer (score 1):

This is NOT an error, it is a warning.  Though it seems well explained enough, it means that you're potentially not using anything from the resource you've defined.  I say potentially as quite often there's a false positive.

TLDR - It's a warning which can be ignored.